# Encrypting archive and then dividing it into many parts

Tags: files, encryption, split

I have a personal archive of many files (more than 12Go)

I want to encrypt it with a password, then divide it into 100 parts.

How can I do so?

And how can I regroup it and de-encrypt it to get the files back?

Comment: to split it up, use `split`; to stitch it back together, use `cat`.  To encrypt, use whichever means you like.

Comment: Divide the problem into two parts. Encryption and split. Both have solutions here already on U&L SE. The converse of `split` (or `csplit`) is `cat`.

Answer (score 2):

To encrypt the file use `openssl`:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -in the_archive -out the_archive.crypted
```

To split the file use `split`:

```
split -a 3 -b 100000 the_archived.crypted chunk.
```

To regroup the chunks use `cat`:

```
cat chunk.??? >the_archive.crypted
```

To decode the file use `openssl` again:

```
openssl aes-128-cbc -d -in the_archive.crypted -out the_archive
```

Comment: No. Never use `openssl` to encrypt something. It's very hard to use correctly, and you didn't (hint: where's the key?). Use a proper tool like `gpg`.

Comment: The key is properly input at the keyboard when `openssl` asks for it.

Comment: You don't input a key at the keyboard. You input a password. And the way openssl derives a key from a password is not good (it isn't slow, and with older versions it isn't salted).

Answer (score 2):

If any of the 100 parts are lost/corrupted you could end up being unable to recover any files, I'd lean more towards 100 separate archives each encrypted.

But, with one giant split file you may end up needing 12Go (Gigabytes?) of free space to re-assemble the pieces, and another 12 to decrypt/view the archive, if your tools don't support pipeing with stdin/stdout.

Using tar & gpg & split together should work, like:

```
tar -c files | gpg -o- ... | split -b [size 1/100th of total] -
```

Options for split that might be useful may include:

- `-a3` generate suffixes of length N (default 2)
- `-d` use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.
- `-` read standard input.
- `outputfilename.` name of output files

Answer (score 0):

To create/encrypt/split:

```bash
tar -cJvpf - inputdirectory/ |
     gpg --symmetric --cipher-algo aes256 |
     split -d -b 100m - outputfile.tar.xz.gpg.
```

Adapted from [How can I backup and encrypt with tar, split and openssl,
all in one command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155876/how-can-i-backup-and-encrypt-with-tar-split-and-openssl-all-in-one-command) on Ask Ubuntu, modified to use gpg instead of openssl.

Tar options:

> `-c` = `--create`
>
>   create a new archive
>
> `-J` = `--xz`
>
>   Filter the archive through
>   `xz`
>
> `-v` = `--verbose`
>
>   verbosely list files processed
>
> `-p` = `--preserve-permissions` = `--same-permissions`
>
>   extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)
>
> `-f` = `--file=ARCHIVE`
>
>   use archive file or device
>   *`ARCHIVE`*

And to decrypt:

```bash
cat outputfile.tar.xz.gpg.* | gpg -d | tar -xJvpf -
```